# Teradata LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS on insert query into a VOLATILE TABLE

Tags: teradata, volatile

I have a `VOLATILE TABLE` in `teradata` that i created with the code below

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE Temp 
(
ID VARCHAR(30),
has_cond INT
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

I want to insert records from a select statement that i have created which is a pretty big SQL statement and definitely requires a row lock before proceeding

```
INSERT INTO Temp 
(ID ,has_cond)
SELECT * FROM....
```

Can anyone tell me how to safely lock the rows so i can insert the records into my `VOLATILE TABLE` as they are production tables and i don't want to lock out some `ETL` that might be happening in the background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can apply a *row lock* for an `insert` unless you put the `select` in a view.

Or you switch to `lock table`, but don't forget to include all tables...

But in most production environments there's a database with 1-1-views including `lock row access`, you can use those (or you might already, check Explain).

Comment: Hi @dnoeth. Thank you very much for the quick response. It seems i can also use `lock tablename for access` to achieve what I'm looking for as the lock would be elevated to table level by the optimizer in most cases...